# Is this update statement missing something?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have made a database where email id and corresponding name and password is stored. I have successfully obtained a form's data.. where the user enters updated name and password. But the problem is occuring with the query which is as follows

```
$db = mysqli_connect(all details)...
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['password']:
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query = "UPDATE mytable SET name='$name',password='$password' WHERE emailid='$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

Though I am getting all form values succesffuly and until and unless I put the 'where' clause.It works.But obviously updates all values. i want it to work with where..but so far unsuccessful :(

Comment: So echo $query;  and then see about using a non-deprecated API like mysqli/ PDO, and prepared statements

Comment: Set before **$query** `var_dump($email); die();. What the value in **$email**?` In mytable exist this value in column **emailid**.

Comment: The MySQL server responds to all queries even if something's wrong. You need to check the server's response because it tells you exactly what's wrong via its [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mysql-error.php) function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `emailid` exists in `mytable`, you truly intended to filter by it and in your database scheme it has a type which supports the posted data. It seems that you are sending strings, like `'foo@bar.lorem'` and your `emailid` is an `int` or something in the database scheme. Check it by running

```
desc mytable;
```

You need to put curly brackets around variables if you use apostrophe around them, but as a matter of style I like to close the string and attach the `$variable` with a `.` as this coding style is closer to me personally.

If everything fails, see what is generated, by echoing out the query string, try to run that directly, see what the error is and fix until...

... until it is fixed.

Also, you do not encrypt the password and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection too. Please, read about [password encryption](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) and [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and then protect your project against these dangers.

Comment: Instead of blindly trying various different things that "might or might not fix the problem" wouldn't it be better to investigate what the problem is?

Comment: Asking the MySQL server "why did you return false on my last query" always works, the MySQL server will tell you "you used a column i don't know about" or "you used a table i don't know about" or "there is a syntax error in your query".

Comment: hey thanx..though curly braces didn't helped,but your idea of printing query was helpful.. n it is successful now :)

Comment: @MihaiStancu, I disagree with your first comment. When there are several potential issues which might cause the problem referred to in the question, it is a good thing to mention them. In many cases (including) this one, this approach can contribute to the solution. Your second comment is kindergarten level, I would rather not answer to comments reaching that level.

Comment: @PrafullMishra, can you tell us what was the problem and what was the solution? Also, if you believe that my post solved the problem, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad on my first comment: finding the root cause of an issue is always more important than fixing the issue even when the issue is easily fixed. That's why learning how to do proper error checking and how to display error messages will take you much further in the long run. Give a man a fish and he'll eat today, teach him how to fish and he'll eat for a lifetime.

Comment: @LajosArpad on my second comment: it's kindergarten level because that's exactly what OP needs -- go to kindergarten, learn the basics, learn how to methodically solve your own problem instead of attempting random incantations you find on the internet which sometimes happen to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put  **{}** around the variables if its surrounded by quote **''**

so your query should look like this

```
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET name='{$name}',password='{$password}' WHERE emailid='{$email}'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

**EDIT :** also before saving data to database make sure to filter and validate data

Comment: There is no need for braces when variables are surrounded by quotes. Braces are useful when you have letters directly after the variable name (and the variable name could be misinterpreted).

Comment: N.B.: your answer does not address the problem itself, it addresses a collateral issue, it should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: It was not working with where clause because email id is not matched .... By putting {} braces proper value for emailid is passed @mihai

Comment: I'm guarantee you that `"WHERE emailid='{$email}'" === "WHERE emailid='$email'"` apostrophes don't require the use of braces around variables.

Comment: You need to use braces around variables only when the variable is immediately followed by a letter or a number or an underscore such as `"{$product}s" !== "$products"` or when the variable is an object and you need to call methods from the object such as `"{$product->getPrice()}"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your statement as:

$query = "UPDATE mytable SET name='".$name."',password='".$password."' WHERE emailid='".$email."'";

using . as string concatenating operator

Comment: I also favor concatenation because the intent of the code is clearer and easier to debug. In cases such as the above where you have many items to concatenate `sprintf` would be much more comfortable to use.

Comment: On the other hand using prepared statements looks and feels like `sprintf` but has many more advantages such as protecting against SQL injection.

Comment: N.B.: your answer does not address the problem itself, it addresses a collateral issue, it should be a comment not an answer.